# Angular 4 same route different component with guards

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I simply ask myself how to implement it when i have 1 route with 2 layouts which leads to the same component?

Here is my routing:

```js
{
  path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
      canActivate: [NoneUserGuard],
        children: [
          { path: 'a', component: aComponent }
        ]
}, {
  path: '',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
      canActivate: [UserAuthGuard],
        children: [
          { path: 'a', component: aComponent }
        ]
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'a' }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the difference?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible using routing only. Can't you just create a login page and a home page ?

Comment: I have a login layout (a) and a logout layout (b). now i have a child route (c). When  i am logged out i want to use (b) for the child route (c). When i am logged in i want to use (a) with child of (c).